# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "api:5000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have searched for hours but I cannot find the root problem cause.This is my docker-compose.yml file you can see below:

```
version: "3"
services:
   postgres:
     image: "postgres:latest"
     environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
   redis:
     image: "redis:latest"
   nginx:
     restart: always
     build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
     ports:
      - '3666:80'
     depends_on:
      - api
      - client
   api:
     build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
     volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
     environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
   client:
     stdin_open: true
     build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
     volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
   worker:
     build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
     volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/app
```

This is my nginx/default.conf

```
upstream client {
        server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
        server api:5000;
}

server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://client;
        }

        location /api {
                rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://api
        }
}
```

When I try :
#docker-compose up --build
This error occured in the process:

***nginx_1     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "api:5000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6***

Comment: is `api` server is reachable on port `5000`?

Comment: @Adiii yes I control in the code: `app.listen(5000, (err) => {
  console.log('Listening');`

Comment: @SabuhiGurbani any soluition to this please?

Comment: @MoonKnight check link please, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/docker-nginx-emerg-host-not-found-in-upstream-web-3000

its caused by depends_on directive.
and add all service to the same network please.      

networks:
      - nginx_network

Answer (score 0):

please check your docker-compose file, you must set api under services

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30022149)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is an error in the API container when it's trying to run, so it crashes and closes down. This results in Nginx failing to connect. Open the logs of the given container, to see what's causing the issue.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/docker-nginx-emerg-host-not-found-in-upstream-web-3000 its caused by depends_on directive. solution: add all service to the same network please. networks: - nginx_network